# RTAB-Map using isaac_ros_visual_odometry

Tags: slam, navigation, ros2, odometry, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Hi there. In order to get some hardware acceleration I want to use the isaac_ros_visual_odometry package as a replacement for the rgbd_odometry node of rtabmap_ros.
Now the rgbd_odometry node publishes the /odom informations, which in turn are required by rtabmap.
isaac_ros_visual_odometry publishes the information in its own format, giving translation and rotation values in x,y,z direction. So unless I'm very much mistaken the information needed is present.
Is there any known procedure on how to transpose an IMU-like message to an odometry message format or else, has anyone tried a similar approach to hardware acceleration before and has had some experience on integrating the isaac-ros GEMS to rtabmap?

Ubuntu 20.04
ROS2 Foxy
Nvidia Isaac GEMS for ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396331/rtab-map-using-isaac_ros_visual_odometry/) by [TurBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/97138/turbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

you can use tf directly to get odometry by setting `odom_frame_id`. Here is an example with a zed2 camera (set those [lines](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros2-wrapper/blob/b512dce6ad4565f4770273995b147122e735ca0f/zed_wrapper/config/common.yaml#L58-L60) to false to avoid zed tf) based on this [example](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/tree/ros2#rtabmap_ros-):

```
ros2 launch zed_wrapper zed2.launch.py
ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link_smooth base_link
ros2 launch isaac_ros_visual_odometry isaac_ros_visual_odometry_zed2.launch.py

ros2 launch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch.py \
    rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" \
    rgb_topic:=/zed2/zed_node/rgb/image_rect_color \
    depth_topic:=/zed2/zed_node/depth/depth_registered \
    camera_info_topic:=/zed2/zed_node/rgb/camera_info \
    frame_id:=base_link \
    odom_frame_id:=odom \
    odom_tf_angular_variance:=0.001 \
    odom_tf_linear_variance:=0.001 \
    visual_odometry:=false \
    approx_sync:=false \
    wait_imu_to_init:=true \
    imu_topic:=/zed2/zed_node/imu/data \
    qos:=1 \
    rviz:=true
```

When using odometry from tf, we don't have a covariance, so we can adjust the fixed covariance with `odom_tf_angular_variance` and `odom_tf_linear_variance` parameters.

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2022-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TurBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/97138/turbot/) on 2022-02-28**:
Thanks a heap. I'm using a Realsense but I suppose I shall be able to port the example. I had tried to read the information from TF and build/calculate and publish an odometry message from it, but your suggestion is what I looked for: a clean and straightforward ROSish method instead of a ramshackle workaround.

Edit: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom I was following this link in building the odometry message. Since /visual_odometry/imu topic appears to be empty but /visual_odometry/tf_stamped is not, this seemed the way to go.

However: now I am using /imu topic directly from camera and working on including the orientation from /visual_odometry/tf_stamped, since /imu has accelerations but not orientation ... apart form getting things to work I want it to be a clean approach as well

**Comment by [TurBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/97138/turbot/) on 2022-03-02**:
Since /imu doesn't contain the orientation I start a separate node which collects orientation data from the /visual_odometry/tf_stamped topic then publishes /imu_pub, containing orientation and velocity/acceleration informations from the original /imu.

However, on running
ros2 launch rtabmap_ros realsense_d400.launch.py 
rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" 
depth_topic:=/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw 
rgb_topic:=/camera/color/image_raw 
camera_info_topic:=/camera/color/camera_info 
odom_topic:=/odom_pub
imu_topic:=/imu_pub 
frame_id:=base_link 
odom_frame_id:=odom 
odom_tf_angular_variance:=0.001 
odom_tf_linear_variance:=0.001 
visual_odometry:=false 
approx_sync:=true 
wait_imu_to_init:=true 
qos:=1 
rviz:=true

I get the following error:
CoreWrapper.cpp:2478::imuAsyncCallback() IMU received doesn't have orientation set, it is ignored.

I don't understand why ROS doesn't "see" the information.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2022-03-06**:
Look at the D400 examples here: http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping, to compute the quaternion of D400 imu message, we use [imu_filter_madgwick](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick):

```
rosrun imu_filter_madgwick imu_filter_node \
    _use_mag:=false \
    _publish_tf:=false \
    _world_frame:="enu" \
    /imu/data_raw:=/camera/imu \
    /imu/data:=/rtabmap/imu
```